# Filter ComboBox by selected item of another ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, combobox

I have a County `ComboBox` bound to an entity (EF). There is another `ComboBox` for Area's. These controls are in an edit form.

So the user has chosen these values. In this form the user can edit the chosen values. So when the window is loaded, the chosen values are selected as default. Each of these `ComboBox`es has an `SelectionChanged` event.

The problem is that when the default value is selected (when the window is being loaded), the `SelectionChanged` event is triggered. Pretty obvious. But I want the event to be triggered only when the user really chooses another item (from County `ComboBox`) to filter the Area `ComboBox`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a public variable. Name it something obvious and intuitive like `EnableEvents`.

An example of using it, with a default value of `True`, would be:

Whenever you do **NOT** want your code to trigger the `ComboBox`'s events, set `EnableEvents=False` and then inside the event handler, use something like a `If Not EnableEvents Then Exit Sub`.

Whether you default this variable to `True`, which will allow all events **unless** when you specifically change the flag to `False`, or default the variable to `False` which will disallow events unless you change it to `True`, is probably a matter of preference based on your specific needs.  Whatever initial value you assign to it, just remember to reset it after each time you change it.